# Apache 2.4: Allow access from the local network only

Tags: windows, wamp, apache2.4

I have a web page on a windows 10, running Apache 2.4 with wamp server on my computer.
I would like to configure Apache so that a given virtual host is only visible from inside the local network, so far our local computer can access my page with setting below:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
Require ip 10.1.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Recently our office has been divided into 2 separate office (different location) but for network when i check using ipconfig. the second office still using the same domain with the first one. How can I configure at the apache so that the local computers at second office will have an access to the webpage?

sample ipconfig from the computer at 1st office.

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.office.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.***
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.250
```

sample ipconfig from the computer at 2nd office.

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.office.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.99.4.**
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.99.5.254
```

I noticed that there is differences at the subnet mask too..

Answer (score 1):

Add the following :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
Require ip 10.1.1
Require ip 10.99.4
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried solution suggested above, seems like not working. My local Web page still cannot access at the second office. Differences between subnet mask doesn't effect? Im sorry, Im not it/network technical person.

Answer (score 0):

Using CIDR notation:
Require ip 10.99.4.0/23

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).